# Editable textfield tableviewcell swift

Tags: swift

I have to display the data of my user connected in textfield in tableviewcell and I wanted to modify them and save them in variables to use them after then what I have to do

Answer (score 0):

The most recomendable is to use custom cells, create the cell in a .xib file.
Here u have basic documentation about this.
https://www.ralfebert.de/tutorials/ios-swift-uitableviewcontroller/custom-cells/

Enjoy this

Comment: Thank you very much this is what I did and I display my data in textfield but I wanted to change the values and save them in variables to use them after (the new values)